# Accessing JMX via HTTP alternatives

Tags: java, jmx

We use MX4J to access JMX related operations/attributes via a web interface in the container itself. I wanted to know if there are alternatives that are available for it, since the last service release for MX4J was in 2006. I am basically looking to overcome limitations of MX4J in handling collections.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was [experimenting](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/03/jolokia-highcharts-jmx-for-human-beings.html) once with [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/features-nb.html) and looks pretty cool. From the webpage:

> Jolokia is an HTTP/JSON bridge for remote JMX access.

Definitely give it a try. I used it successfully to create an AJAX/JavaScript dashboard displaying configurable JMX metrics on refreshable charts.

Comment: Thank you @Tomasz Nurkiewicz. Jolokia definitely looks promising; the only downside being a _0.9x_ release rather than a >1.0 and not coming from an apache/sourceforge stable - not to say that the code is not great . Has anyone tried jminix yet? [link](http://code.google.com/p/jminix/) Even this boy is a _0.9x_ but not as active as jolokia from the looks of it.

Comment: Be assured, Jolokia will go 1.0 in late summer, early autumn this, year. Jolokia (and its cousin jmx4perl) is used at many large side, mostly for Nagios monitoring. So, I guess Jolokia is a good bet (that been said by the author ;-)

Comment: BTW, Tomasz, congratulations to your [excellent blog](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/03/jolokia-highcharts-jmx-for-human-beings.html) on using Jolokia together with Highcharts, it is really nice. Something like this (plus a bit more) is already on the roadmap for a Jolokia Dashboard, deployable along with the client.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [jminix](https://github.com/lbovet/jminix) quite a while. I give it thumbs up, well worth a try!

Comment: jminix looks nice, less clutter than MX4j HttpAdapter for sure. It feels a bit slow... and killed my Google Chrome browser :-/ Antoher problem with the ajax UI, as always, it that is makes it boring to browse and have the UI state to persist (or bookmark some pages)

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, I've recently added a little web server to my [SimpleJMX](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/jmx_web_http.shtml) package.  It exposes beans from the platform MBeanServer to HTTP via Jetty if in the classpath.  There is also text versions of all pages that make it easy to scrape.

For more details see: 
[Is there any JMX - REST bridge available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571600/is-there-any-jmx-rest-bridge-available/22020821#22020821)

Answer (score 0):

You have MX4j and its HttpAdaptor

Ah sorry, just read the OP question properly, he mentions MX4j and asks for alternatives ... at least you have a link and screenshot now :-)

http://mx4j.sourceforge.net/docs/ch05.html
[image: MX4j HttpAdaptor with its XSLTProcessor]