# Using same port for Server and remote JMX beans

Tags: java, spring, jetty, jmx, jconsole

We are using Embedded Jetty as our webserver running on port 8080 and want to monitor the application on Jconsole. We are using the following system property when starting the Jetty server specific to JMX:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=jmxremote.access  
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=jmxremote.password   
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote   
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true   
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false   
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8081
```

Although, JMX and Webserver are running on two different ports, is there a way for client to access JMX via Jconsole/JvisualVM using port 8080? Is JMX Proxy going to help me in anyway? Is it possible in any way?

Thanks in advance.

Ajay

Answer (score 1):

Not without some effort. In a nutshell, there can always only be a single server on one port (or the other way around: Servers can't share a port).

If JMX was supporting HTTP requests, then you could run it as a servlet on the same HTTP server. There would be one port (used by the HTTP server) and then the HTTP URLs would allow the server to determine whether the client wanted to talk to JMX or the web application.

But JMX doesn't support HTTP requests directly. You can try [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/features-nb.html) ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077299/accessing-jmx-via-http-alternatives)) or you can write servlets which allows a client to query certain mbeans (but without JMX protocol).

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Cant i do something like a redirection from within the server, so user (Jconsole user using url like service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://host:8080/jmxrmi) can still see that port they are using is 8080 while internally application figures out the actual port i.e. 8081 for client and does the needful?

Comment: As I said in my answer, Jolokia does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

`JMX` specification have `Connector` that can use any protocol as transport, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Jmxarchitecture.png